# Linking a CSS File to a HTML File

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a navigation bar for my site using Notepad++ but my CSS code for the navigation bar won't link to my HTML file. I've tried linking the files together using this method:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
```

But it doesn't seem to make any changes to my HTML file.

Here is the HTML code that I would like the CSS code to link to:

```
 <ul id="nav">
     <li><a href=" ">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href=" ">Popular Stories</a></li>
     <li><a href=" ">Q&A Page</a></li>
     <li><a href=" ">Popular Stitch Sessions</a></li>
     <li><a href=" ">Video Stories</a></li>
     <li><a href=" ">Secrets Section</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the CSS code that I would like to be linked to the HTML code:

```
/*CSS Document*/
* {margin:0px; padding:0px;}
body {
    width: 600px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif:
    font-size: 86x;
}

/*NAVIGATION*/
*nav {
margin-bottom:20px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;

}
*nav li {
   display:inline;
   margin-left:-3px;
   margin-right:-3px;
}

*nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:#999;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom:10px; 

}

*nav a:link{

}

*nav a:hover {
   background-color:#FFF
}

#nav a:visited {
}
```

Comment: Where did you include this code? Are your HTML file and your CSS file in the same directory?

Comment: As long as you are putting that code in the page head and the main.css file is in the same folder, it should work.

Comment: I used the code to turn several list items into a navigation bar and they are in the same directory.

Comment: You might want to share some HTML and CSS code. It could be that it's reading the file, but just not applying any styles because of bad selectors.

Comment: Okay I'll edit my question and add the code now.

Comment: The reason it's not working is not because it's not detecting the CSS file, but because you are using asterisks instead of pound signs. CSS IDs are indicated by #, just change all instances of *nav to #nav and you'll be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an asterisk for your ID selector. It should be a hash tag (`#nav`, not `*nav`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the rest of the HTML should look like assuming your CSS file is in the same folder:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Stylesheet Linking</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep file in same directory than in your htmml file type below code

`<!doctype html>`
`<html>`
 `<head>`
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">`
`</head>`
`<body>`
`</body>`
`</html>`